# Power BI Cyclic relationship

Tags: powerbi, relational-database

I have a scenario where I'm getting a circular relationship in Power BI. Just a little background,
Shown below my vw_all_metallic is my base table, I have created two subsets Last Status & Created on from the base table, which gives me the two tables based on when the ticket was created and when its Status was last updated. I created a date column to show both cases created and the count of cases when their status was changed on the same date axis.

Now I need to filter this graph based on customer status in my base table of vw_metallic. I added the column in both my subsetted table. I can join my subsetted table with the base table on the case number, it's a unique column, but when I join both tables, I get a circular relationship.

In a nutshell, I want to filter my graph below based on the customer status. I'm out of ideas on how to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, check if you can build better star model.  eg. keep CreatedDate and LastStatus in FactTable (add unique key to point Status and Creat table as independant relationship). 

You can create an inactive relationship (Fact to Date for Status or Created), then in measure, we can use USERELATIONSHIP to make it active (only in the scope of this measure).